# Displaying only property name from property file using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a vendor properties file and it has property name and values. Now I have to read property file and display only property names.

Below are some property names and its values.

```
ipaddr=10.1.1.1,12.4.5.6
ports=2345
location=anywhere
```

I want my output to display like below

```
ipaddr
ports
location
```

I used the following command to read the file:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\run.properties" | 
    Where-Object {!$_.StartsWith("#") }
```

Comment: I  used following command ....Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\run.properties" | Where-Object {!$_.StartsWith("#") } ... but this gives both property name and value. But i want only property names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *regex* to remove the values:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\run.properties" |
     Where-Object {!$_.StartsWith("#") } | 
     ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '=.*'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115812/45375):

For ***small* files** such as properties files, you can both ***simplify and speed up* processing** by **reading all lines *up front*** and then **using PowerShell's *operators***, many of which can operate on *array-valued* LHS values:

```
@(Get-Content "C:\Test\run.properties") -notmatch '^#' -replace '=.*'
```

- `@(Get-Content "C:\Test\run.properties")` reads all lines of the input file into an array

  - `@(...)`, the array sub-expression operator, ensures that the result is indeed an *array*; otherwise, if the file happened to contain only a *single* line, you'd get a *string* back, which would change the behavior of `-notmatch`.
- `-notmatch '^#'` only outputs those array elements (lines) that do not start (`^`) with a `#` char.
- `-replace '=.*'` the operates on the remaining lines, effectively removing the part of the line that starts with `=`. (`.*` matches any sequence of characters through the end of the line, and by not specifying a *replacement* string, the matching part is effectively *removed*).

The **fastest alternative** is presumably the use of **`switch -file -regex`**:

```
switch -file -regex "C:\Test\run.properties" { '^#' {continue} default {$_ -replace '=.*'} }
```

- `-file` tells `switch` to process the lines of the specified files one by one.
- `-regex` tells it to interpret the branch conditionals (`'^#'`, in this case) as *regular expresions*.
- Branch conditional `'^#'` again matches lines that start with `#`, and `continue` proceeds to the next input line, effectively ignoring them.
- Branch conditional `default` applies to all remaining lines, and, as above, `$_ -replace '=.*'` removes everything starting with the `=` char. Automatic variable `$_` represents the input line at hand.